# How to detect character sets encoding for all of language?

Tags: c#

I have a .smi file.
When i open with notepad++ i had:

```
<font color="#FF8040"><I>- °øµ¿¹ø¿ªÀÌ´Ùº¸´Ï Áö¸í°ú ÀÌ¸§ÀÌ ¾à°£¾¿ Æ²¸±¼ö ÀÖ½À´Ï´Ù.-</I></font>
```

Then i set Character sets > Korean > UEC-KR:

```
<font color="#FF8040"><I>- 공동번역이다보니 지명과 이름이 약간씩 틀릴수 있습니다.  -</I></font>
```

So, what can i do it in C#? I want when i open a file, app can detect Character sets and display in a richtextbox.
I used:

```
System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(openFile.FileName);
inputText.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
inputText.SelectAll();
inputText.SelectionFont = new Font("Arial Unicode MS",9,FontStyle.Regular);
```

Result in inputText:

```
<font color="#FF8040"><I>- ���������̴ٺ��� ����� �̸��� �ణ�� Ʋ���� �ֽ��ϴ�.  -</I></font>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell your `StreamReader` to use the appropriate encoding when it reads the file. You can achieve this by changing the first line with:

```
var krEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("euc-kr");
System.IO.StreamReader sr = 
    new System.IO.StreamReader(openFile.FileName, krEncoding);
```

This is possible because the `StreamReader` constructor has an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143456%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that accepts an encoding as an argument.

Comment: Can i make it automatic? Just open a file, app can get System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(Enconding code)..

Comment: @user3172506 No, please see the link provided by Mormegil as a comment to the question. There's no such thing as *reliable encoding detection*. The best you can do is run some heuristics that would work   for a limited set of scenarios. [You basically have to know the encoding beforehand](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Answer (score 0):

I haven seen any *.smi yet so my answer can be bogus to some point but:

1. if the file is in raw 16bit unicode

   - then any char is coded as 2 bytes
   - look the file as binary and see the first two BYTEs
   - it should be FF,FE [hex]
   - it is the raw 16bit UNICODE coding signature
   - after that any character is set of two BYTEs: 'ASCII',codepage
   - read the codepage bytes and see what language it is...
   - or use full unicode font
2. if the file is in UTF-8 / UTF-16

   - detect codepage from coding of extended characters (see unicode documentation)
   - or use full unicode font
3. the data inside *.smi can be coded differently then the file itself

   - in that case look in smi documenattion for codepage tags
   - if it has none then you out of luck
   - if it does then you shoul use the tag for decoding ...

**PS. there are not many unicode fonts out there and none is complete !!!**
From the better (more pages supported) I know only of:

- Quivira
- unifont (be aware this one is bitmap font !!!)
- but i have not done any research in the area for about a year so situation could change...